# gcov-tool merge: "not a gcov data file"

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, gcov

I'm trying to use gcov-tool to merge some existing coverage data (which I did not create myself) for several source files. But when I invoke `gcov-tool merge dir1 dir2` where `dir1` and `dir2` are the directories containing the `.gcda` files which I intend to combine, I am instead confronted with `./SOME_FILE.gcda: not a gcov data file` errors for each file in `dir1`.

At first I assumed that the coverage files must be corrupted but then I had a look at the `gcc-6.3.0` (which matches the version of `gcov-tool` I have installed) source code (`libgcc/libgcov-util.c`) in which that error message seems to be printed only if the first few bytes of some `.gcda` file do not match the magic ASCII string 'gcda'. Yet `hd dir1/SOME_FILE.gcda` yields:

`00000000  67 63 64 61 36 30 33 2a  17 68 64 3d 01 00 00 00  |gcda603*.hd=....|`

and so on.

Has anyone dealt with something similar before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out, it was an endianness issue. I was looking at the wrong check inside the gcc code which actually tests for both little and big endian .gcda files. gcov-tool does not do this (which I find odd) so it seems you have to execute it on a machine with the same endianness as the one the coverage data was generated on.